# OnTriggerEnter2D() seems to not work unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a platform game, where a ball should be able to move left and right and to jump. I could make the character jump or move successfully, but when i tried to check if it was on the ground, by creating an element as child of the character, with a trigger collider 2D, and wrote the code using a variable that was supposed to be true when the player was touching the ground, and false when it wasn't, it just did not activate.

Here is the code for the main movement script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grounded : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Player = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (GetComponent<Collider2D>().tag == "Ground")
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (GetComponent<Collider2D>().tag == "Ground")
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the **Grounded** script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or information is really appreciated.

Comment: A bit too much GetComponent you use for my taste

Comment: is the trigger actually marked "is trigger"? Otherwise [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) is called.

Comment: On top on all these tips:
Use `Component.CompareTag("Ground")`
This prevents Unity from cluttering your stack with strings.

Comment: @KYL3R yes, it is marked "is trigger"

Comment: @ecco it produces an error. How does it work?

Comment: [CompareTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) `collider.CompareTag("Ground")` in your case. Don't compare the players tag, as you are interested in the thing you just hit instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
GetComponent<Collider2D>().tag == "Ground"
```

you are checking the `tag` of this GameObject's (child of Player) collider itself!

You probably rather wanted to check the `tag` of the thing you collided with.

Also avoid repeated `GetComponent` calls .. rather do it only once.

(Thanks @Jichael) You should also rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of using `tag == "XY"`. It is [more efficient](https://caolam.com/unity-tips-use-comparetag-instead-of-string-equals) and also actually checks if the given compare string exists as tag. If not an error is thrown while using `==` simply returns false which makes it hard to find evtl. typos.

```
// Would be better even to already reference this via Inspector
[SerializeField] private Move2D Player;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!Player) Player = GetComponentInParent<Move2D>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        Player.isGrounded = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        Player.isGrounded = true;
    }
}
```

---

The same also in `Move2D`

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComppnent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Jump()
{
    // This is very small but it is slightly cheaper to check the 
    // isGrounded value so this order is minimal faster if isGrounded is false
    if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

---

Also note: Whenever a Rigidbody is involved you should not control the position via the `Transform` component but rather use [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) to keep the Physics intact!

This has to be done however in `FixedUpdate` so your code would become something like

```
private Vector3 movement;

void Update()
{
    Jump();
    movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
}

void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

---

Whether both objects require a Rigidbody or only the player depends on the ground objects (afaik):

- ground objects are static → one (player) Rigidbody is enough
- ground objects move → both need a rigidBody (the ground e.g. a kinematic)

Comment: Good answer but I would also recommend using CompareTag instaed of ==

Comment: @Jichael ofcourse you can do that .. I don't know if it changes much since not even the Unity docs itself is consequent on that ..

Comment: It should be way more efficient, https://caolam.com/unity-tips-use-comparetag-instead-of-string-equals/

Comment: @Jichael ok thanks for the info! "Way more efficient" for a difference of `1.5ms` for 10k operations is a bit exaggerated but sure even a little bit more efficiency is a good argument. The more important one for me would rather be the error thrown for unknown/wrong strings which is really a good thing to have!

Comment: Yeah, meant more like "better to use", but I'm picky, needs those ms lol

Comment: @derHugo This fixed my problem perfectly! Thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Could you check both ball and ground has a rigidbody? which is required to trigger a trigger.

*Note: Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody attached. *

Also could you change your code

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (GetComponent<Collider2D>().tag == "Ground")
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = true;
    }
}


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Ground")
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = true;
    }
}
```

Also I also recommend to use "layer" instead of using tag

Comment: Thanks for your help!